# Center content with min and max length and single tag

Tags: html, css, layout

Can we reach same effect code below with single tag?

The spec is:

1. The content has minimal and maximal width.
2. If viewport with is less than content maximal width, content takes the viewport with.
3. If viewport with is more than content maximal width, content must be centered.
4. The border-bottom takes always 100% of viewport width.

Well, I suppose it could be impossible because of different color of centerer and it's parent, so I'll remove different colors condition.

```css
.Component {
    background: #FFCC80;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #283593;
}

.Centerer {

  min-width: 100px;
  max-width: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
  /* ↓ Does not matter */
  background: #81D4FA;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Component">
  <div class="Centerer">
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, what exactly do you need? Please state your problem again. I ran the code snippet and it appeared centered.

Comment: Simply remove the parent `div.Component`

Comment: @AlePlo, I edited my question. The short answer on your question: I need same displaying as in snippet but with one tag instead of two.

Comment: @Chaska, thank you for the answer. I complicated the problem a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes like below:

```css
.Centerer {
  padding: 0 calc((100% - 300px)/2);
  min-width: 100px;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(#81D4FA 0 0) content-box, 
   #FFCC80;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #283593;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  

  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="Centerer">
  some text here
</div>
```

Comment: It's your fifth solution of my CSS problem. Is there something in CSS that you can not do? I don't think so.